# Issue with $(this).next()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

For some reason only the save button is showing up on the edit click...not sure why I am having problems with the cancel button...? Below is my code

```
$(".editlink").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      var dataset = $(this).prev(".datainfo");
      var savebtn = $(this).next(".savebtn");
      var cancelbtn = $(this).next(".cancelbtn");

      $(this).css("display", "none");
      cancelbtn.css("display", "block");
      savebtn.css("display", "block");     
});
```

This is my entire HTML page:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <section id="core">
      <div class="profileinfo">

          <div class="gear">
              <label>Primary E-Mail:</label>
              <span id="email_address" class="datainfo"><?php echo $row['email_address'] ?></span>
              <a href="#" class="editlink">Edit Info</a>
              <a class="savebtn">Save</a>
              <a class="cancelbtn">Cancel</a>
          </div>

          <div class="gear">
              <label>First Name:</label>
              <span id="first_name" class="datainfo"><?php echo $row['first_name'] ?></span>
              <a href="#" class="editlink">Edit Info</a>
              <a class="savebtn">Save</a>
              <a class="cancelbtn">Cancel</a>
          </div>

          <div class="gear">
              <label>Last Name:</label>
              <span id="last_name" class="datainfo"><?php echo $row['last_name'] ?></span>
              <a href="#" class="editlink">Edit Info</a>
              <a class="savebtn">Save</a>
              <a class="cancelbtn">Cancel</a>
          </div>

          <div class="gear">
              <label>About Me:</label>
              <span id="about_me" class="datainfo"><?php echo $row['about_me'] ?></span>
              <a href="#" class="editlink">Edit Info</a>
              <a class="savebtn">Save</a>
              <a class="cancelbtn">Cancel</a>
          </div>

          <div class="gear">
              <label>Interests:</label>
              <span id="interests" class="datainfo"><?php echo $row['interests'] ?></span>
              <a href="#" class="editlink">Edit Info</a>
              <a class="savebtn">Save</a>
              <a class="cancelbtn">Cancel</a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </section>
```

For some reason everything I have tried hasn't worked. I can get one label/field to work, but when I have multiple like above in my html, the cancel button shows up.

Comment: `next` doesn't work this way. Check out the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/next)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var cancelbtn = $(this).parent().find('a.cancelbtn');
```

[See working example](http://jsfiddle.net/EdrEw/7/)

Comment: I tried it, and I still get the same issue...In your example copy and paste your html that way you have two. I have four but it should give the same result.

Answer (score 7):

`next()` as described in the jQuery Docs:

> Get the **immediately following sibling** of each element in the set of
>   matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next
>   sibling only if it matches that selector.

Try using [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: The problem I am running into now is that once I click on Edit all of the buttons are shown for each label. So I have in my HTML email, name, address, etc...each has the same class.

Comment: Is there a way to try and add 'this' this this statement?

var savebtn = $(".savebtn,.cancelbtn").css("display", "block");